# Handle button click in Xamarin Forms Android to Navigate to new page

Tags: android-activity, lambda, xamarin.forms, buttonclick, android-navigation

I am trying a simple Android app using Xamarin Forms with C# for the coding. In my Main.axml there's a button, on clicking which I'd like to go to a new page, say XInfo.axml.

Now this is my MainActivity.cs:

```
    using System;
    using Android.App;
    using Android.Content;
    using Android.OS;
    using Android.Runtime;
    using Android.Views;
    using Xamarin.Forms;
    namespace AlberoPizza
    {
        [Activity(Label = "Albero Pizza", MainLauncher = true, Icon="@drawable/icon")]
        public class MainActivity : Activity
        {

            protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
            {
                base.OnCreate(bundle);
                //// Set our view from the "main" layout resource
                SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
                // Get our button from the layout resource,
                // and attach an event to it
                Button btn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);
                btn.Clicked += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {

            };



        }


    }
}
```

Now, I am finding it difficult to structure code inside my Lambda which would handle the navigation to the page, whose name I mentioned. There is no Navigation Bar and there cannot be any navigation bar. Also, for the existing code block, I am getting this error, which is quite weird to me:

> Error CS0311: The type 'Xamarin.Forms.Button' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Android.App.Activity.FindViewById(int)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Xamarin.Forms.Button' to 'Android.Views.View'. (CS0311) (AlberoPizza)

I thought this is how we usually find controls in Android app Xamarin. Can you help me complete the code for this? I'm sure it's a pretty basic type of scenario. There is this persistent error on the one hand and the code to navigate to XInfo.axml on the other. I've tried stuff like Activator.CreateInstance, the PushAsync, etc. inside the lambda, but more errors show up and entire thing becomes more and more complicated.

Comment: You're mixing Xamarin Android code with Xamarin Forms code.  That doesn't work.  You can use both in the same app, but in a controlled way, not just mixing them interchangeably.

Comment: Hi @Jason.
So how do you recommend, I proceed?
From the 'using' block, I guess I should remove Xamarin.Forms? Please reply on this.

Also, what about the code for moving onto XInfo.axml .. some help needed on that part too.
Reply.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, remove the Forms code.  This [guide](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/hello,android_multiscreen/) has a good intro to writing a multi-page Android app

Comment: Hi again, @Jason.
Yes, done that and also seeing the Xamarin link to the multiscreen concept.

Here a question I have, they are using Intent to do the navigating, like this: 

var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(CallHistoryActivity));
StartActivity(intent);

where the 'CallHistoryActivity' is an activity itself, extending from ListActivity.

In my scenario what should I do, do I pass directly name of my file, 'XInfo.axml'? If not, then how do I modify the concept for my scenario?
Thanks.